# Generate numpy.arrange from a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list `list_a=[4.0, 8.0, 0.5]` and i need to get `numpy.arange(4.0, 8.0, 0.5)`

Issue is i tried to strip the square brackets from my list and place into the numpy.arrange() but it copied as a string

```
import numpy

list_a=[4.0, 8.0, 0.5]
list_a_strip=str(list_a)[1:-1]

print(f"numpy_arange: {numpy.arange(list_a_strip)}")
```

Error is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

But when i manually put the values in, all looks good

```
import numpy

list_a=[4.0, 8.0, 0.5]
list_a_strip=str(list_a)[1:-1]
​
print(f"numpy_arange: {numpy.arange(4.0, 8.0, 0.5)}")
```

```
numpy_arange: [4.  4.5 5.  5.5 6.  6.5 7.  7.5]
```

So how i can generate the numpy.arange() from a list?

Comment: `np.arange(lista[0], lista[1], lista[2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argument unpacking to send the arguments to `np.arange` in the order you have them in the list.

```
import numpy as np

list_a=[4.0, 8.0, 0.5]
np.arange(*list_a)

# returns: 
array([4. , 4.5, 5. , 5.5, 6. , 6.5, 7. , 7.5])
```

Comment: wow..where is this in the documentation

Comment: Right here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Comment: got it...thanks!

Comment: how do i print the unpacked list from `[4.0, 8.0, 0.5]` to `4.0, 8.0, 0.5` for another variable `list_b`..for example i can print with `print(*list_a, sep=", ")` but any easier way to have `list_b` for example print `4.0, 8.0, 0.5`

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  What is `list_b` in this case? You may want to open this as a new question on SO.

Comment: how to assign the unpacked list value `4.0, 8.0, 0.5` of `list_a` to a variable `list_b`? so if i do `print(list_b)` it returns `4.0, 8.0, 0.5`...what i want to do is use this for other part of the code

Comment: The list unpacking cannot be held without a container, like a list or a tuple.  You can hold it in 3 variables using `a, b, c = list_a`, but you cannot assign an unpacked list to a single variable.

Comment: yeah thought as much as it treats as a string..cool thanks

Comment: ok here is error am getting for a list `long_list_x` of value `[5.5, 9.5, 1]`, manually `long_list=np.arange(5.5, 9.5, 1)` works fine but when i have this `long_list=np.arange(*long_list_x)` i get error `TypeError: arange() takes from 0 to 4 positional arguments but 13 were given`

Comment: if i print `np.arange(*long_list_x)` it prints same as `np.arange(5.5, 9.5, 1)` but when used in above i get that error, you know why?

Comment: seems unpacking the list does not work when it is a parameter of a function..i am using this `long_list=np.arange(*long_list_x)` as parameter to another function

Comment: found issue `long_list_x` of value `[5.5, 9.5, 1]` was showing as a string! i thought it was a list...crazy